# Module dependency in Android Studio - build errors

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio

I'm trying to use a module dependency for my Android app, and have set up the directory structure like this:

```
- root
    - main (my app's module)
        - build
        - src
        - build.gradle
        -  ...
    - libs
        - PagerSlidingTabStrip
            - library (the library module which I am trying to use)
               - build
               - src
               - build.gradle
               - ...
            - sample
               - ...
            - ...
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - ...
```

I've added to my root `settings.gradle` file the following line:

`include ':libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip:library'`

And, to main/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip:library')
}
```

The library project appears to build fine, but I get errors like 'no resource identifier found for attribute' and 'class not found' with references to my modules's files - so it seems like my 'main' module is somehow unable to find the compiled library's files.

I've checked that libs/PagerSlidingTabStrip/library/build.gradle contains `apply plugin: 'android-library'`

Comment: Why not use `compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to add: I'm using a different fork.